# How to get the value of a key in object inside an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, oop

I have an array of objects. With some logic I am returning the **id** of some selected objects. What I need is to get the value of **name** property of that selected objects.
I have only one thing to process which is the **id** of that selected objects.

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: You can `.filter()` array based on `id` property

Comment: Assuming I understand what you mean, either a) loop through the array and find the object with the given id, return its name, or b) re-index your array into an object, where the id is the key and the object is the value, which allows you direct access by id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Try like this

```js
var a ={name:"bb"};
    
console.log(Object.keys(a)[0]);
```